# Div should be above other div, not below

Tags: html, css

just got back into coding and I can't solve this simple problem so any help much appreciated.

Basically the 'header-top' (red) div should be at the top, and the 'header-bottom' (blue) div should be at the bottom. However, the top div just sits below the bottom div. Why is this? I've tried float, clear and margin commands to no avail.

thank you. code below:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 background-color:#ff0; 
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns content to touch the edge; gets rid of default spacing/margin between edge and content */
}

/* Header */
#header-wrap{
 background:#0F0;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
#header-top{
 /* contains logo & title text */
 background:#F00;
 width:960px;
 height:200px;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns centrally */
}
#header-bottom{
 /* contains navigation menu */
 background:#00F;
 width:960px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<!-- Meta Tags Below -->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title>___________________________</title>
<!-- Google Analytics Code Below -->
<!-- _____________________________ -->
</head>

<body>
<div id="header-wrap">

<div id="header-top">
<div id="header-bottom">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you blue div needs to be absolute positioned

Comment: Your HTML is incomplete, you are missing closing div tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Please close `div` elements.

```
<div id="header-wrap">
   <div id="header-top"></div>
   <div id="header-bottom"></div>
</div>
```